# Gradle for Rubyists ... Equivalent of `bundle install`

Tags: gradle

Is there a command similar to `bundle install` or `npm install` to install Gradle plugins?

Comment: Are you looking for `gradle build` ? Using intelliJ it installs the librairies by default.

Comment: @Sylhare I want to make sure all the plugins are preinstalled inside a Docker image that runs builds with Gradle

Answer (score 1):

The command `gradle tasks` is likely to download all plugins in case they contain tasks, and unlikely to have other undesired effects.

Comment: I'll try using that in my build